# AS3 write string to an existing text file

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm running my program on AIR. I want my game to save the high score to a text file so it can be stored when the program is closed. I've tried using filestreams, however I've found that the application directory is read only. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The application directory is read only? That seems odd but at any rate can't you just save it to a different directory?

Answer (score 0):

The AIR [application storage directory](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a4c56-7fc6) is designed for saving these sorts of preferences and user settings:

> For every AIR application, there is a unique associated path that
>   defines the application storage directory. This directory is unique to
>   each application and user. You can use this directory to store
>   user-specific, application-specific data (such as user data or
>   preferences files).

Access it through the `File` class:

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory; 
file = file.resolvePath("prefs.xml");
```

See also: [Reading from and writing to an XML preferences file](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/xml_prefs.html)

The only caveat I have found with using this directory is that it does not get removed when the AIR app is uninstalled using the .air installer/uninstaller.